# Ending a question in 'Exam' class

Tags: exam

I am making a document in the 'exam' class and here's what I want to happen.

```
\question This is part of the question

This is no longer part of the question and is not indented as such.
```

I know this is a total noob question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To end the question, you need to either end the `questions` environment or start a new question.  You can accomplish what you want, though, by using the `\fullwidth` command, as in `\fullwidth{This is no longer part of the question and is not indented as such.}`